# Which application to install on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for audio/video cutting?

Tags: audio, video

I want an application (like ffmpeg) for cutting my audio / video files.

I'm unable to install ffmpeg or avconv on my current system Ubuntu 14.04 although it was there in my previous versions.

What application can be installed on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for the same?

Comment: The first answer to this question elaborates on the missing ffmpeg package: http://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04

Comment: If you want software recommendation, it is offtopic here. If the question is about installing ffmpeg, follow the link above.